# Please inform me how to maintain the order of POJO class after executing REST url(JERSEY)

Tags: java

Hello Every one please let me know how to maintain the order of POJO class after executing REST.

```
@GET
    @Path("/Encounter")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @JsonPropertyOrder(alphabetic = false)
    public List<Encounter> getEncounterDetails(@QueryParam("patientId") Long patientId) throws JSONException, IOException {

        List<Encounter> enlist = new ArrayList<Encounter>();

        service = new MyappImpl();
        enlist = service.getEncounterDetails(patientId);
        return enlist;

    }
```

Output
{
        "current": null,
        "encounterId": 67,
        "name": "xyz",
        "overdue": null,
        "patientId": 624
}

But my POJO class order is
encounter Id , 
name...

Comment: What Json parser / library are you using?

Comment: hi @Bhavani , go to my example and test it, It will work definitely , as i have tested the same.

Answer (score 1):

Get Rest API json output in Order as you define.


A Sample Example is written here.
Please define Json Property Order to get the value as you want.

```
package com.example.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

@JsonPropertyOrder({ "id", "name", "dept"})
public class Student {

@JsonProperty("id")
private int id;

@JsonProperty("name")
private String name;

@JsonProperty("dept")
private String dept;   

//getter and Setter

}
```

OutPut :

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Name 1",
        "dept": "CSE"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Name 2",
        "dept": "B-Com"
    }
]
```

Comment: [How to not be a spammer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion).

Comment: I have Tested this Example and it is working exactly how you wrote the JsonPropertyOrder serial.

Comment: For me, it's not working. what could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

A JSON object's properties by definition do not have an order, just like most simple Map objects.

Since you access those key/value pairs by their key anyway, this shouldn't matter.

Comment: Thanks , But I have requirement to implement it. Can you please suggest me how to implement it?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend going about this. This could later come back to haunt you when you try to integrate with some other application that uses a standard JSON library that will break your structure. Instead, I'd try to explain the reality to whoever came up with this requirement.